# Finishing activity doesn't show previous

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have four Activities, call them A, B, C, D. 
From A, you can start B, and from B you can start C and from C D.

Using Intent I'm starting new Activities:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity D extends Activity A:

```
public class D extends A 
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to close Activity D, Activity C should be displayed, but instead of that, Activity B is displayed. Finishing other Activities, like B,C works fine (always previous Activity is displayed). 
I tried to finish D with finish(), super.onBackPressed(), also tried calling new Intent and starting C from it, but always Activity B is shown. I have no idea why.

Why is not C displayed, when I'm finishing D?

**Edit:**
I found out that onResume() of Activity C is called, but then on next line of log is: Application terminated. , and Activity B is shown. There is no code in onResume() in C, so still no clue what's wrong there.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting flags here?

Comment: Opening already created instances of Activities if they exists.

Comment: What's the purpose of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? Why do you want to launch all activities in separate task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do create a new Task everytime? and CLEAR_TOP?

Just create a plain intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

wouldn't that exactly be what you want?

Oh, and I hope you exchange `B.class` in each intent with the Activity you actually want to show? Or is this the reason why "always activity B is shown"?

See more information about Activities and the Task Back Stack here [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: I've tried this but no change. But I found out that onResume() of Activity C is called, but then on next line of log is: Application terminated. , and Activity B is shown. There is no code in onResume() in C.

Comment: Are you watching the log from the "run" window? Look at logcat in the "Android monitor". To track this one down I suggest you put a log line in every onCreate and onDestroy of each of the activities to see who is triggering when

Comment: Log of every onCreate, onResume and onDestroy helped me to figure it out. Thanks.